# File Download Not Working On Non-WiFi Network On BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, download, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to download a zip file by using the following code;

```
HttpConnection httpConn = null;
InputStream inStream = null;
int responseCode = 0;

String connParams = "  ;interface=wifi;deviceside=true;";
httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(src + connParams);

responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
if (responseCode != HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    throw new IOException("Response: " + responseCode);
}

// Other relevant code
```

This way, when using the `interface=wifi;deviceside=true;`, its working fine. This means I've to depend upon the WiFi network. But I want to download files using the 2G/3G link. For this, I tried the same code after removing the `interface=wifi;` connection parameter. But its throwing `IOException: tunnel failed` exception.

Please guide me about what do I've to do make it work on non-WiFi network.

I am developing in the following environment;

- BlackBerry JDE Eclipse Plugin 1.5.0
- BlackBerry OS 4.5
- BlackBerry Bold with a 3G card

Comment: please refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5075107/1075066

Comment: Already tried. Result is same; IOException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I had this problem before, I decided to do some processing to know the best connection type at a moment, here is the code I used:

http://www.localytics.com/blog/2009/how-to-reliably-establish-a-network-connection-on-any-blackberry-device/

Answer (score 1):

On BlackBerry 4.5, you still have to worry about properly appending a suffix on to the end of your connection strings.

```
interface=wifi;deviceside=true;
```

is a valid connection string suffix if you only want to use the Wi-Fi connection.  For more information on supporting the many other types of *transports* that BlackBerry supports, you can see my (2) answers to [this similar stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068959/get-suffix-string-for-blackberry-connection-on-4-6-1).  In one answer, I point you to links on the BlackBerry website.

In the other answer, I post some sample code that contains an algorithm to select a transport, and create the connection string suffix for that transport. See the methods like `getWifiConnection()`, `getBesConnection()`, `getSimConnection()`, etc. for examples of proper suffixes.